# Ajax get dynamic id for the submit button of the form PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form in PHP & MySQL and I want to submit it with AJAX.

I Have similar data so I have put these data in a foreach loop.

The problem is that when I try to submit the first row data it all goes well but it changes the data in all rows. and when I try to submit other data except the first row it doesn't submit at all.

I think the problem is because the submit button always gets the same id and therefore goes to the first row always.

I don't know how to get the value in Ajax.

Here goes the code:

```
      //php form

           <?php
            $pid = $_GET['pid'];
            include('config.php');
            $timeline_query="SELECT * FROM timeline_table WHERE pid=$pid";
            $result_timeline=mysqli_query($conn,$timeline_query);
            if(!$result_timeline){
                echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
            }
            $timelines=array();
            while($row_timeline=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_timeline)){
              $timelines[]=$row_timeline;
            }
          ?>
              <?php
            $x = 0;
            foreach ($timelines as $timeline):?>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="heading<?php echo $x; ?>">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?php echo $x; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<?php echo $x; ?>">
                    <?php echo $timeline['timeline_title'];?>
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse<?php echo $x; ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<?php echo $x; ?>" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form id="register_form">
                     <input type="text" id="tid" name="tid" value="<?php echo $timeline['tid']; ?>"/>

                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" id="timeline_description" name="timeline_description"><?php echo $timeline['timeline_description'];?></textarea>
                    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <?php $x++; endforeach;


   // ajax function
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    var timeline_description = $("#timeline_description").val();
    var tid = $("#tid").val();
    alert(timeline_description);
    alert(tid);
    // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    // var dataString = 'timeline_description='+timeline_description+'&pid='+ pid + '&tid='+ tid +;
    var dataString = 'timeline_description='+timeline_description;
    alert(dataString);
    if(timeline_description=='')
    {
      alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    }
    else
    {
      // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.php?tid"=+tid,
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      alert(result);
    }
  });
  }
  return false;
  });
});

  //process.php
   <?php
   include('config.php');
   $tid=$_GET['tid'];

 if( $_POST['timeline_description']==NULL ){ $timeline_description=''; } 
 else { $timeline_description=$_POST['timeline_description']; }

  $query_timeline = "UPDATE timeline_table SET 
  timeline_description='$timeline_description' WHERE tid=$tid ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$query_timeline);
   if(!$result){
   echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
 }
?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: "I have a form in PHP & MySQL..." - no, You have not. You've got form in HTML :)

Comment: hahahaha exactly @bigwolk

Comment: This is so hard to understand.

Comment: Please edit your post so the problem is **reproducible** so we can debug it. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You've duplicate `id`'s you need to replace them with common classes instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id of elements must be unique. The abnormal behaviour of your code is due to non-unique ids of your input elements.

In the case, If you cannot assign unique ids to elements you can achieve desired output by using **this** keyword and **siblings()** method in jquery.

Instead of

```
var timeline_description = $("#timeline_description").val();
var pid = $("#pid").val();
var tid = $("#tid").val();
```

try to get values in this way.

```
var timeline_description = $(this).siblings('#timeline_description').val();
var pid = $(this).siblings('#pid').val();
var tid = $(this).siblings('#tid').val();
```

Comment: Thank you I understand my problem completely. How can I do the same for the id of the submit button?

Comment: instead of id you can use class.
$(".submit").click(function(){});

Comment: thank you.. but using non unique ids is not a good practice. Instead of id you can use class for your input elements too. and get value using

"var tid = $(this).siblings('.tid').val();"

Answer (score 1):

I see there a problem with Yours inputs id - `<input type="text" id="pid"` - this is in `foreach`, so You have multiple elements with same id. So `var pid = $("#pid").val();` will return You always a value of first found element. Try to use arrays:

```
<input type="text" id="pid[$pid]" name="pid[$pid]" value="<?php echo $pid ?>"/>
<input type="text" id="tid[$pid]" name="tid[$pid]" value="<?php echo $timeline['tid']; ?>"/>
```

Please remember one thing: `id` of any element in html PAGE (whole document) must be unique.

Comment: The problem is not the pid because it should be the same. But I think the problem is the tid.

Comment: @Tinchu It was just example how it should looks like. I've edited my answer with second input and rule to remember :)

Comment: I realized that I don't need pid it works just with tid.(Just updated the code) But you are right I need somehow to change the id of the submit button because it completely works for the first row but not the others. How can I do that?

Comment: In the same way :) But I don't know if better solution wouldn't be call Your method by `onclick` attribute on the button. Just create named method in JS which will send Your form and add to your buttton `onclick="your_send_method()"`